# How to resolve ambigious Class resolution in composer PHP?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have got problem with ambigious class resolution during composer install. I know where this problem came from. It is because I put new verion of PHPExcell library in folder next to the old one:

[image: Ambigious class names]

I did this because I need some things from new version but i don't want to delete old because a lot of things are using it.

So my question is: Can i somehow add a kind of prefix before New_PHPExcel so I would be able to use both ?
Thank You in advance! :)

Comment: Composer version 1.3-dev (23d2e5600a91746fe4c2e19621431eeac21f174e) 2016-10-04 10:20:39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use 2 versions of the same library simultaneously in PHP.

Composer won't help you with that.

See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2167